# How to hide weekends with p:calendar - PrimeFaces 6.2

Tags: primefaces

I'm using PrimeFaces 6.2.

```
<p:calendar id="calendar" 
    inputStyleClass="calendar_retour" 
    value="#{returnService.date}" 
    locale="fr"
    rendered="#{returnService.displayCalendar}" 
    showOn="button" showButtonPanel="true" 
    readonlyInput="true"
    disabledWeekends="true"
    mindate="#{returnService.todayDate}"
    placeholder="__/__/__"
/>
```

I was able to disable weekends with :

```
disabledWeekends="true"
```

However, I don't find any solution to hide the Saturday and Sunday "columns".

[image: calendar]

Do you have an idea ?

Comment: Sure I have an idea: try CSS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested by Kukeltje, CSS was the answer.

The class used for the Saturday and Sunday columns is **ui-datepicker-week-end**

```
.ui-datepicker-week-end {
    display: none;
}
```

Below is the result :

[image: calendar_after]

Comment: Out of curiosity, why did you not try this before asking this question?

Comment: @Kukeltje It happens :p